# momentJS Timezone fails while converting into unix time

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to convert times from different timezones into unix time.
For example:

```js
var spain = moment.tz("18/03/2014 00:00", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", "Europe/Madrid").unix();
var chile = moment.tz("18/03/2014 00:00", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", "America/Santiago").unix();
```

After these lines, both variables have the same value in my System (currently in Madrid time: 1395097200). AFAIK, the unix time should represent the number of seconds since 1970/01/01 0:00:00 UTC.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that moment-timezone.js version was outdated in the official webpage. Now, it works correctly.